# how to get background color of an event click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I would like to get `background-color` of a `div` element.
I define a handle `click` but it doesn't work at all.

it's my code:

```
 <div  className="column" onClick={this.handleClick}>a</div>
```

---

```
handleClick(e){
    let a = e.target.style.background; //or backgroundColor  returns nothing.
    console.log(a);
}
```

the my output is empty.

I would like to use `if` statement for my colors. for example my color is black and I wish to get `black` color name.

Comment: and are you sure there is a background set ? if not it's logic to get empty

Comment: yes.of course.i set backgroud color in css in class column

Comment: You now had multiple people confused over this question. Instead of saying "of course" to everyone, how about you just provide a fully working minimal example in the question? Also, are you really using jquery with React?

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a slightly different structure:

```
<div id="column-1" class="column">a</div>
```

---

```
$('.column').click(function(e) {
    var bColor = $(this).css('background-color');
    console.log('Background color of this div: '+bColor)
});
```

Sorry, I don't use reactJS, but hopefully this is enough to help you.

Comment: This isn't the correct solution when using ReactJS even if it works for multiple reasons, the biggest being it's going to get overwritten by React's virtual DOM.

Answer (score 0):

So, I read in comments you said you're using Reactjs.
There is a lot of way to access styles of your element.
This is one of ways:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';

    export default class Example extends PureComponent {

     handleClick = () => {
       console.log(findDOMNode(this.El).style.backgroundColor);
     };

     render(){
      return(<div 
          className="column"
          ref={(El) => { this.El = El; }}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            a
          </div>);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). This function makes it possible to get the style no matter how the styles where defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div  className="column" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>a</div>

handleClick = e => {
let a = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
console.log(a);}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to get the `div` you clicked you should use `e.currentTarget` rather than `e.tartget`.

Secondly you are setting the `backgroundColor` with a CSS class, this way `div` doesn't have a `style.background` property. If you `console.log('e.currentTarget')` you can see that its going to print

```
 <div className="column">a</div>
```

If you are setting background color with different `className`s you can do something like below;

```
handleClick(e){
    let cName = e.currentTarget.className;
    switch(cName) {
      case 'redBox':
        console.log('It is a red box');
        break;
      case 'blueBox':
        console.log('It is a blue box');
        break;
      default:
        console.log('I don\'t know the exact color');
        break;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simplest way to get style as like background-color using jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Testin script</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .btn-hot{
        background-color: red;
        color: white; 
    }
</style>
<body>


    <div onclick="get_my_bg_color(this);" style="min-height: 50px;background-color: red;">

    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function get_my_bg_color(me){
            console.log($(me)[0].style.backgroundColor);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not clear to me exactly how you are doing this, however it appears you are using React syntax. If you are using react the problem could be that the handleClick method is not bound to this in that context.

Comment: I would like to get a color of a div element then I can change another one  depending on first element.

Comment: Are you using React?